# How Do I Repeat A Question Until Valid Input WIthin A Series Of Questions?

Tags: python

I want the questions to be asked and if im almost done answering all the questions and I type an integer into a string spot It repeats the question and not repeat from the beginning like it does.

I have tried putting every input in a loop and making an else for invalid input, but that is inefficient and doesnt really work.

```
def create_entry():
    c = connection.cursor()
    tables = ["Cpus", "Cores", "Manufactures", "Sockets"]
    print(tables)
    while True:
        tables_display = input("What Table Do Want To Make An Entry Too? ")
        append_table_cpu = input("What Is The Name Of Your Cpu You Are Adding? ")
        append_table_cost = input("How Much Does The Cpu You Are Adding Cost? ")
        append_table_speed = input("How Fast Is The Cpu That You Are Adding?, Write Like This 2.00GHz")
        append_table_cores = input("How Many Cores Does Your Cpu Have? ")
        append_table_threads = input("How Many Threads Does The Cpu You Are Adding Have? ")
        append_table_socket = input("What Type Of Socket Does Your Cpu Use? ")
    tuple_insert = (tables_display, append_table_cpu, append_table_cost, append_table_speed, append_table_cores, append_table_threads, append_table_socket)
    sql_query = ("INSERT INTO Cpus (Name,Cost,Speed_GHz,Cores,Threads,Socket) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
    c.execute(sql_query,tuple_insert)
    results = c.fetchall()
    for i in results:
        print("Id:  Manufactures: ".format(i[0],i[1]))


while True: #Puts Everything In A Loop
    try:        
        option_1 = int(input("What Would You Like To Do To The Cpu Database, 1) Make An Entry, 2) Read The Data Or 3) Delete Data. Type 1, 2, ,3 "))
        if option_1 == 1:
            create_entry()   

    except: 
        print("Please Type A Valid Reply")
    continue
```

I want to be able to type an integer into a string column for my database or an invalid reply like a non existed table name, and it repeat the question I was on an not from the beginning. Please keep the answers basic.

Comment: With all due respect, I am not sure you fully understand `while` loops (the first `while True:` loop probably needs a `break` condition).

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to validate inputs. Ask inside a while, if the input matches the regex, add the input to `answers` and continue asking; if it does not, show a message and ask again (continue the loop). Here an example (extract of your code):

```
import re
tables = ["Cpus", "Cores", "Manufactures", "Sockets"]
questions = [
  ("What Table Do You Want To Make An Entry To? ", "({})".format("|".join(tables))),
  ("What Is The Name Of Your Cpu You Are Adding? ", ".*"),
  ("How Much Does The Cpu You Are Adding Cost? ", "\d+"),
  ("How Fast Is The Cpu That You Are Adding? (e.g. 2.00GHz) ", "\d+\.?\d*[GMT]?Hz"),
  ("How Many Cores Does Your Cpu Have? ", "\d+"),
  ("How Many Threads Does The Cpu You Are Adding Have? ", "\d+"),
  ("What Type Of Socket Does Your Cpu Use? ", "(DIP|PLCC|Socket\s?[1-8])")
]
answers = []
for question, regex in questions:
  while True:
    answer = input(question)
    if re.fullmatch(regex, answer):
      answers.append(answer)
      break
    print("Invalid value")
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO Cpus (Name,Cost,Speed_GHz,Cores,Threads,Socket) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
c.execute(sql_query, answers)
```

Also the last loop is going to ask forever, do not forget to add an option to stop asking and `break` the while-loop.

Comment: @DanteMarshall What doesn't work? Could you be more specific?